# Vertically scrolling two frame layout or fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried this-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/shop_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm trying to get two vertically scrollable fragments in one screen. The above code is only showing fragment one and it's also not scrolling. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to change the RelativeLayout into LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments are overlapping in your case. if you want to use Relative layout then use it as below,

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/shop_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/shop_detail_container"
            android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

or use Linear layout as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/shop_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Hey @Akash, Thank you, man! It really helped me to accomplish what I was trying to do. Height was not showing correct so I used this `itemDetail.getLayoutParams().height = windowHeight;`
`shopDetail.getLayoutParams().height = windowHeight;`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this it worked for me

```
<LinearLayout...orientation = "horizontal>

    <ScrollView>
        <FrameLayout/>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView>
        <FrameLayout/>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```